# Possible timestamp error of posted question?

Tags: support, questions, timestamps

See this question, which according to OP was posted in october 2016:
[Systematic Component of Variation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207354/systematic-component-of-variation?noredirect=1#comment479849_207354), and its comment thread:

> I put the question in October 2016. There is something wrong in the time setting of SO

but is dated as asked Apr 14 at 16:54 and presented as asked 8 months ago

So something is certainly wrong!

Comment: The OP probably mis-remembers.  The question was posted in April, saw little activity, and then was modified in November.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by whuber the OP in [Systematic Component of Variation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207354/systematic-component-of-variation?noredirect=1#comment479849_207354) probably mis-remembered the date of posting, as he admit in one comment under the same question:

> Maybe I was wrong.

It is ok to ask a question based on an OP's impression, but usually a bug would be something reproducible, able to collect evidence (e.g.: steps to reproduce the problem, screenshots, different users reporting same problem on different SE sites, etc).